# When using Transparent Data Encryption for SQL Server 2012, can you use different encryption keys for each database?

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2012

I am new to using TDE for SQL Server and one of the requirements that a client has is that their database be encrypted using a different key that is unique to only their database.  I was wondering if that is possible and how that is accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Create a different certificate for use with only that database.